# What happened to 'Stars!'?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, stars

'Stars!' was a complex 4X game in the mold of Master of Orion.  It was a fantastic game from the mid-90's written by an independent group. It was distributed using the shareware model with the upgrade key available for purchase. After it finally got retail distribution, it disappeared.

Does anybody know what happened to it?

Comment: +1 for asking about Stars! This game ate up wayyyyy too much of my youth. Fantastic game, though. Always wanted to get a network game going but never did...

Comment: Stars! always looked to me like an update to the DOS-based game Planets.  I loved both and still have my Stars! serial number saved, if only I could find a working disc...

Comment: +1 What a great game... I'm going to have to try to find a copy this weekend.

Comment: This was not a question about development per se, it was a simple question on whether the game was still available and / or have active users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game is still playable and still played.  It works in 32-bit Windows 7, and almost anywhere using DOSBox running Win 3.11.  To obtain the game and serial codes to play, see http://wiki.starsautohost.org/wiki/Get_Stars!.

Answer (score 4):

According to the one retail outlet I found for it, Empire Interactive isn't making it anymore.

Sources:

http://www.starsfaq.com/fileinfo.htm

http://stars.lelv30.net/

Comment: The second link got broken :(